Mongoose server has stopped suddenly
We are making a movie database and the server suddenly stopped working. I deleted the original code and rewrote it and this is where the problem comes at.
Here what the teacher said:
Solving mongoose.connect issues

If you are using the latest versions of Node.js with mongoose, and you get a connection refused ECONNREFUSED error message when connecting your app to the database, then you might need to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your mongoose.connect database connection string:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your_database_name_here')
Also, in the currently newest mongoose versions you don't need to pass the options object as the second argument to the mongoose.connect method.
Therefore, when using the newest mongoose versions, your mongoose.connect call can look just like shown above, without adding an object with options such as useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useCreateIndex, or useFindAndModify.

I tried both what the teacher said and what's on mongoose website
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your_database_name_here')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test')
.then(() => {
console.log("Connection OPEN")
})
.catch(error => {
console.log("OH NO error")
console.log(error)
})

This is the error:
$ node index.js
OH NO error
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017       
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\\Colt The Web Developer Bootcamp 2023\redo\node_m
odules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\\Colt The Web Developer Bootcamp 2023\redo\node_
modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },        
    stale: false,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

I tired redoing the code and then I created a new folder and reinstalled the npms

Firstly, I don't think mongoose let's you call .connect() multiple times.
When I copy your code in a new file, it gives me this error.
MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

As shown in mongoose multiple connections:
You can do:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function connectionFactory() {
  const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

  conn.model('User', require('../schemas/user'));
  conn.model('PageView', require('../schemas/pageView'));

  return conn;
};

And to get data:
const connectionFactory = require('./path/to/connectionFactory');
const conn = connectionFactory();

const User = conn.model('User');
const PageView = conn.model('PageView');

User.find({}).then(users => console.log(users));
PageView.find({}).then(pageViews => console.log(pageViews));

Secondly, I think you should use reference ref if you want to get data from multiple collection.
For eg:
Movie.js
//movie schema
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  director: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Director' //reference to the Director model
  }
});
const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

Director.js
//director schema
const directorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});
const Director = mongoose.model('Director', directorSchema);

And you can do something like this to get directors:
Movie.find()
  .populate('director') //it replaces the objectId with the director document
  .then(movies => {
    console.log(movies); //you will now see director's detail/document
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

Now moving towards your error:
ECONNREFUSED means your mongodb server isn't running or isn't accessable.
1. It might be due to how you are connecting.

mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/test
mongodb://localhost:27017/test

First, try these 3 first.
If it doesn't work:
For Windows: Press the Windows + R keys on your keyboard. Type services.msc and press Enter. Scroll down and search for MongoDB.exe. Right click on it and press Start.
On Linux/mac
sudo systemctl status mongod
and then,
sudo systemctl start mongod
If you are getting the same error:
Make sure nothing is blocking port 27017, firewall or any other app can block that port.

I wrote the 2 connect That i tried I only had one when i ran it. thank you, someone sent me this video and it solved my problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1l1UI_UdQI

@OsamuMidoriya I have mentoined about it at the last. Take a look at For Windows section below the 2 connect that you mentioned about.
